# mySQL query across all databases

Tags: mysql, drupal

I have a query which I would like to run across all databases except the few listed.

However it only seems to run on the DB I have open in workbench.

I have used multiple results to create this query but not sure why it doesn't give me the required result.

This is for multiple drupal db's where I would like to obtain the db name as well as emails for that role within the users table.

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("SELECT database(), u.mail FROM ",schema_name, ".users u INNER JOIN ",schema_name,".users_roles ur ON u.uid=ur.uid INNER JOIN role r ON ur.rid=r.rid AND r.name = 'System Admin'") SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
  INTO @stmt_sql 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables 
WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema','backup','dbname', 'test');
PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This I think is showing me all users with the System Admin role however i'm not able to see which database those users are linked to.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What database is `role` in?  Please provide a sample of the `SELECT` you are trying to generate.  Instead of doing `PREPARE` etc, do just `SELECT @stmt_sql;` so we can see the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE information_schema.TABLES\G` to see what the problem is.  The name is `TABLE SCHEMA`.

(There may be more problems in the query.)

The `SELECT` is expected to generate many `SELECTs`, correct?  Start by removing `INTO @sql` and see what you get.  It will be one line per database.

Without another loop (in a stored procedure or client code) you cannot run those selects.  I suggest you copy & paste them to manually run them.